# Grouping by specific subset of ids

Tags: pandas-groupby

Consider the following code.

```
d=pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'a'],[3,'c'],[4,'a'],[4,'c']],columns=['A','B'])
```

I want to group by a specific set of ids in column A - those ids which map to c. In this case, it is 2,3,4. I wrote the following code for it.

```
d.groupby(d[d['B']=='c'].A).size().to_frame('size')
```

It returns

```
A size
2  1
3  1
4  1
```

but I want it to return

```
A size
2  2
3  1
4  2
```

because I want size to indicate the number of rows containing the value in A. What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Solved.

```
d.groupby(d.A).filter(lambda x:{'c'}.issubset(x["B"])).groupby(d.A).size().to_frame('size')
```